# UseState value is not changing on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements, setstate

If **newAvailableQuantity** is greater than or equal to **minOrderQuantity**, I want to set the **newMinOrderQuantity** equal to the **newAvailableQuantity**. So i put a condition

```
 if (newAvailableQuantity >= minOrderQuantity) {
     setNewMinOrderQuantity(newAvailableQuantity)
 }
```

and **setNewMinOrderQuantity** according to the condition. Then I send the new value to backend. But the value of newMinOrderQuantity is not changing. It is always getting the previous value. What am I doing wrong here?

```
const ProductPurchase = () => {
    const { productId } = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [orderLoading, setOrderLoading] = useState(false);
    const [user, userLoading] = useAuthState(auth);

    const { availableQuantity, minOrderQuantity, productDescription, productImage, productName, productPrice, _id } = product;
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
    const [newMinOrderQuantity, setNewMinOrderQuantity] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setQuantity(minOrderQuantity);
        setNewMinOrderQuantity(minOrderQuantity);
    }, [minOrderQuantity])

    //load user clicked product
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/product/${productId}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
                    signOut(auth);
                    navigate('/login');
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                setProduct(data);
                setLoading(false);
            })
    }, [productId, navigate])

    if (loading || userLoading || orderLoading) {
        return <LoadingSpinner></LoadingSpinner>
    }

    const handleIncrement = () => {
        setQuantity(prevCount => prevCount + 10)
    }
    const handleDecrement = () => {
        setQuantity(prevCount => prevCount - 10)
    }

    const handlePlaceOrder = (e) => {
        setOrderLoading(true);
        e.preventDefault();
        const address = e.target.address.value;
        const phone = e.target.phone.value;
        const userName = user?.displayName;
        const email = user?.email;
        const itemId = productId;
        const itemName = productName;
        const itemImage = productImage;
        const orderQuantity = quantity;
        const totalPrice = quantity * productPrice;
        const orderedProuct = {
            address,
            phone,
            userName,
            email,
            itemId,
            itemName,
            itemImage,
            orderQuantity,
            totalPrice
        }
        //send order to db
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/order', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`,
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(orderedProuct)
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.insertedId) {
                    // update available stock quantity
                    const newAvailableQuantity = (availableQuantity - quantity);
                
                    if (newAvailableQuantity >= minOrderQuantity) {
                        setNewMinOrderQuantity(newAvailableQuantity)
                    }
                    const newStock = {
                        availableQuantity: newAvailableQuantity, 
                        minOrderQuantity: newMinOrderQuantity
                    }
                    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/product/${_id}`, {
                        method: 'PUT',
                        headers: {
                            'content-type': 'application/json',
                            authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(newStock)
                    })
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            if (data.modifiedCount > 0) {
                                setOrderLoading(false);
                                toast.success('Order placed successfully');
                                navigate('/dashboard/myorders');
                            }
                        })
                }
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) React hook works.

### `useState`

When you call the `useState` hook, it returns the current value for that state variable and a setter function to change that value. The first time it is called, it uses the passed argument as the current value because it doesn't yet exist in the React environment.

When you call the setter function, it changes the value that is stored in the React environment, **NOT** the value of the variable in your current scope. This is why it appears that your variable is not being updated; because it isn't, and it's not supposed to. Only the environment variable is updated, and thus you wont see that new value until you retrieve it from the environment on a future render (when your component rerenders and calls `useState` again).

Remember, this is a function component, which is really just a function that happens to return a React element. But in the world of JavaScript, it is just a function. It starts at the beginning and runs to the end. Notice that typically when calling `useState`, you assign the values to `const` variables. If these are constants, how can they be updated? Well, because on future rerenders, they will actually be all new variables being declared for the first time.

### An illustration

State in function components is basically a list of values.

```js
const state = [a, b, c]
```

When your function component renders, it does so by calling the function itself.

```js
const myComponentInstance = MyComponent()
```

Each time it calls the `useState` hook, it simply indexes into the big state array based on the number of times `useState` has been called.

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState() // returns [state[0], (newA) => { state[0] = newA }]
  const [b, setB] = useState() // returns [state[1], (newB) => { state[1] = newB }]
  const [c, setC] = useState() // returns [state[2], (newC) => { state[2] = newC }]
}
```

This is why all renders of a function component must have the exact same number of hook calls and they must be in the same order (see [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)). Otherwise, the values returned from the environment would get mixed up.

### Solution

To solve your problem, you need to either not store your value in a state variable (which is perfectly fine if the value doesn't need to persist between renders), or you need to allow for the component to rerender after setting the state value before you access it.

Alternatively, you may be able to call [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) instead of `useState` which always returns a value immediately. But it comes with some other nuances.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I used let variable with condition instead of state and seems its working fine.

Comment: If it answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer.